# urlrewriter.net work on ASP.NET web server but not on IIS 6 shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

anyone know how to "make work" urlrewriter.net component on IIS 6 ? 
Actually i have this web.config section :

```
<section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />
```

And the rule is, for example:

```
<rewrite url="~/tag/(.+)" to="~/default.aspx?tag=$1" />
```

It's work on the ASP.NET Developmnet server, but not when i go to my shared hosting web site !!! :(

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ask your hosting provider to add a [wildcard mapping](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx) to make the ASP.Net ISAPI handler execute for all requests.

[Instructions](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) (Scroll down to IIS6 Extension-less URLs)

Comment: I'm not sure of your answer.. i've read on ScottGu blog that with url rewriting dll component, you don't need to change anything on the server !
Are you sure ?

Comment: [Read it more carefully](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx). He's talking about IIS 7.  (only)